# node.js elasticsearch API query search request sending a POST method instead of GET

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using the elasticsearch API for node.js to make the [following](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search) query to aws elasticsearch.

The [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) says that the request body search uses the GET method.

I'm using wireshark to look at the request send by my application with the body search method and I see that the method used is a POST.

[image]

Why is sending a POST? I want to allow only GET request to my domain.

elasticsearch.js

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-central-1' });

var elasticClient = elasticsearch.Client({
  hosts: [ 'host' ],
  connectionClass: require('http-aws-es'),
  log: ['error', 'warning'],
    amazonES: {
        region: 'eu-central-1',
        accessKey: 'accessKey',
        secretKey: 'secretKey'
    }
 });

var indexName = "indexName";

var type = "records";
    function querySearch(data){
        console.log("[INFO]: Check data "+JSON.stringify(data));
        return elasticClient.search({
            index: indexName,
            type: type,
            body:  data
        });

    }

    exports.querySearch = querySearch;
```

index.js

```
var elastic = require('./elasticsearch.js');
    elastic.querySearch({"query": {"bool": {"must": [{ "match": { "id": "value" } }]}}}).then(function (resp) {
        //If data doesn't exist in elasticsearch insert into Firehose
        if (resp.hits.hits.length == 0){
            console.log("[INFO]: No data");
        }else{
            console.log("[INFO]: Record already in Elasticsearch");
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.trace("[ERROR]: "+err.message);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I go through `elasticsearch`  module and found that in `search` using `POST`.

```
pi.search = ca({
  params: {
    includeTypeName: {
      type: 'string',
      name: 'include_type_name'
    },
    ......
    method: 'POST'
});
```

Link : [filePath](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js-legacy/blob/16.x/src/lib/apis/master.js)

Comment: could you please update the filePath link to the latest one?